# Multiple checkbox validation in php-mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 6 checkbox, If all of them are checked it goes to the next step. But it is giving error :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&&' (T_BOOLEAN_AND) in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice_login\release_cause_report2.php on line 143

```
<?php if($_POST['Date'] == 'Date') && 
if($_POST['ASR'] == 'ASR') && 
if($_POST['ACD'] == 'ACD') && 
if($_POST['CER'] == 'CER') && 
if($_POST['TQI'] == 'TQI') &&
if($_POST['min'] == 'min')
{?>

<li><label>Date </label><input type="checkbox" id="Date" name="Date"></li>
<li><label>ASR </label><input type="checkbox" id="ASR" name="ASR"></li>
<li><label>ACD </label><input type="checkbox" id="ACD" name="ACD"></li>
<li><label>CER </label><input type="checkbox" id="CER" name="CER"></li>
<li><label>TQI </label><input type="checkbox" id="TQI" name="TQI"></li>
<li><label>TQI </label><input type="checkbox" id="min" name="min"></li>
<li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></li>
```

Comment: @WuerfelDev is right, there should be an extra pair of parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to combine if-statements you can add the statements inside the brackets of the if. It is not possible to write an `if` inside if.

Write this instead:

```
<?php
if(($_POST['Date'] == 'Date') &&
($_POST['ASR'] == 'ASR') &&
($_POST['ACD'] == 'ACD') &&
($_POST['CER'] == 'CER') &&
($_POST['TQI'] == 'TQI') &&
($_POST['min'] == 'min'))
{
?>
```

Or shorter:

```
<?php if($_POST['Date']=='Date'&&$_POST['ASR']=='ASR'&&$_POST['ACD']=='ACD'&&$_POST['CER']=='CER'&&$_POST['TQI']=='TQI'&&$_POST['min']=='min'){?>
```

And maybe you have to add `isset` to check if the `$_POST[]` query is set:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['Date'])&&isset($_POST['ASR'])&&isset($_POST['ACD'])&&isset($_POST['CER'])&&isset($_POST['TQI'])&&isset($_POST['min'])&&$_POST['Date']=='Date'&&$_POST['ASR']=='ASR'&&$_POST['ACD']=='ACD'&&$_POST['CER']=='CER'&&$_POST['TQI']=='TQI'&&$_POST['min']=='min'){?>
```

Comment: Now getting a new error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file", have searched the other stackoverflow question, and used as suggested regarding the php tags.

Comment: @Ayaz would be useful to see the whole file

Comment: @Ayaz Have you a closing bracket `}`?

Comment: Yes, at the end <?php } ?>

Comment: @ WuerfelDev many thanks. Yes i actually had another if statement at the beginning which has closing tag, but i missed the closing tag for this statements.

Answer (score 1):

check if the checkbox values are set, also check how `if` statement is used

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit']){
    if(!isset($_POST['Date']) && 
    !isset($_POST['ASR']) && 
    !isset($_POST['ACD']) && 
    !isset($_POST['CER']) && 
    !isset($_POST['TQI']) &&
    !isset($_POST['min']))
        {
            //all checkbox should be checked
         }
   }?>

<li><label>Date </label><input type="checkbox" id="Date" name="Date"></li>
<li><label>ASR </label><input type="checkbox" id="ASR" name="ASR"></li>
<li><label>ACD </label><input type="checkbox" id="ACD" name="ACD"></li>
<li><label>CER </label><input type="checkbox" id="CER" name="CER"></li>
<li><label>TQI </label><input type="checkbox" id="TQI" name="TQI"></li>
<li><label>TQI </label><input type="checkbox" id="min" name="min"></li>
<li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></li>
```